# How to print access logs of spring boot's tomcat logs to console in eclipse

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat

When I use the following config and access the spring boot controller apis I see the access logs are getting printed in a log file.

[25/May/2023:19:37:42 +0530] 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 "GET /myendpoint/test HTTP/1.1" 200 (3 ms).

But I want this to get printed to the console. Any inputs for this?

```
server.tomcat.basedir=my-tomcat
server.tomcat.accesslog.enabled=true
server.tomcat.accesslog.pattern=%t %a "%r" %s (%D ms)
```